# Something basic; why do I get two different bounds on $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + n^{-1}}} + \sqrt{x^2 + n^{-1}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $n$ be a natural number. Let $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + n^{-1}}} + \sqrt{x^2 + n^{-1}}$.

since $x^2 + n^{-1} \geq x^2$, it follows that 
$$|f(x)| \leq \frac{x^2}{|x|} + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}.\tag{1}$$
But
we can also write
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + n^{-1}}}(2x^2 + n^{-1}) \leq \frac{(2x^2+1)}{|x|}\tag{2}.$$ 
As $x \to 0$, we get different limits in (1) and (2). I don't understand this... why does writing $f$ like in (2) give me something worse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not "writing $f$ like in (2)", you are *estimating* $f$ by **another function**. There are infinitely many functions you can estimate $f$ by, with different limits at $0$.

Let's take a simpler example: $f(x)=\sin x$. I can estimate $f$ as $$|f(x)|\le |x| \tag{1}$$ and the limit of the function on the right as $x\to 0$ is $0$. 
I can also estimate $$|f(x)|\le |x|+42 \tag{2}$$ and the limit of the function on the right as $x\to 0$ is $42$.

Both (1) and (2) are valid inequalities. What they tell me about $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ is another story... Estimate (1), by virtue of Squeeze Theorem, tells me $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$. Estimate (2) does not; so it's not as useful to me as (1).

Similarly in your case: the second estimate is more wasteful than the first, and less useful. Instead of $\sqrt{x^2+n^{-1}} \le \sqrt{x^2+1}$ you in effect use $\sqrt{x^2+n^{-1}} \le \frac1{|x|} (x^2+1)$, where the right hand side blows up at $0$.